# Экранирование HTML для отправки POST запросом. C#

Tags: c#, html, post, экранирование

Необходимо POST запросом отправить на сервер HTML страницу. HTML хранить специальные символы, вроде <,& и тд, из-за которых возникает ошибка 500 сервера. Код отправки запроса:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
postParametrs = new NameValueCollection();
postParametrs.Add("Body", body);
var response = webClient.UploadValues(url, postParametrs);
```

body - строка, хранящая HTML страницу, url- адрес куда отправляется запрос.

Как экранировать строку body, чтобы отправить ее POST запросом?

Comment: Вообще-то проблема на стороне сервера, это он должен преобразовывать те символы, которые он считает для себя опасными.

Comment: Сервер не имеет права надеяться на добрые намерения клиента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось отправить запрос не получив ошибку при использовании любых символов таким способом (используется .net core):

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient()
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "adress", client.Email },
    { "body", body},
    { "theme", theme }
};

var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, encodedContent);

var content = response.Content;
            string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(str)`

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
postParametrs = new NameValueCollection();
body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(body);
postParametrs.Add("Body", body);
var response = webClient.UploadValues(url, postParametrs);
```

Ну и если потребуется на сервере используйте `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str)`

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httputility(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: К сожалению ваше решение мне не подходит. У меня нет доступа к серверу, который получает запрос. А если в строке body будет например "&#" это вызовет ошибку сервера 500.

Comment: Входная строка: `<test>&Alib&aba</test>` / Выходная строка: `&lt;test&gt;&amp;Alib&amp;aba&lt;/test&gt;` что вам не подходит-то?)

Comment: вы уверены на 100%, что символ & приводит к ошибке?

Comment: "вы уверены на 100%, что символ & приводит к ошибке?" Нет. К ошибки приводит комбинация &#. И у меня нет возможность раскодировать экранированные символы обратно на стороне сервера который получает POST запрос. Мне нужно экранировать символы таким образом, чтобы сервер-получатель получил чистый HTML без экранирования, вытащив его из body переменной запроса

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте заменять все подобные символы на специальные символы, например

```
& = `&amp;`,
< = `&lt;`
```